# DOMParser parseFromString method not working as expected

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xml-parsing, domparser

I'm trying to use the DOMParser to parse a string of html as a document object. This is what I've done:

```
<code>
  let parser = new DOMParser();
  let url = document.getElementsByClassName("a-link-emphasis")[0].href;
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
      let doc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/xml");
      console.log(doc);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
</code>
```

I parse the response from the url as text so that the data variable is equal to the html source code of the page specified. It should be equal to a stringified version  [of this page's source code.](https://www.amazon.co.uk/LEGO-31058-Dinosaurs-Triceratops-Pterodactyl/product-reviews/B01J41DNWM/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_btm?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews) This is the console.log of the data variable:
[image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuR0T.png)

However when I try to parse this string with the parseFromString method, the variable doc is equal to the following html elements

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><body><parsererror style="display: block; white-space: pre; border: 2px solid #c77; padding: 0 1em 0 1em; margin: 1em; background-color: #fdd; color: black"><h3>This page contains the following errors:</h3><div style="font-family:monospace;font-size:12px">error on line 1 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name
</div><h3>Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.</h3></parsererror></body></html>
```

Does anyone know what could be doing this?
Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Why not `console.log()` the text *before* trying to parse it? That's where the error is.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for the reply. I did console log the data variable (the variable containing the html string) and posted a screenshot of it in the question. To me, this looks like valid html - although clearly it isn't. I've been trying to figure out what's wrong with it, especially since it's taken directly from the above linked webpage and not changed at all.

Comment: Well one thing of note is that the content is HTML but you're asking the DOM parser to parse XML.

Comment: @Pointy Well.... that took an embarrassingly long time to figure out. Thanks very much for spotting that.